# Raising errors for typos in HTML

Tags: html, css, rel

I just spent an hour trying to figure out why a CSS script wasn't loading.  It turns out it was because I typed:

```
<link rel="styelsheet" href="path/to/script">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/script">
```

It would have been nice had Firefox said something to me, like `styelsheet is unknown`, or whatever.  I would have realized the typo immediately.  Any way to get that in the console?

Comment: isn't there a FF plugin for this? it finds broken links and images

Comment: My guess is you'll never do that again -- an hour well spent :)   Seriously, though, I use sublime text with the emmet plugin cuz I got fat fingers and bad eyesight.

Comment: WebStorm will warn you of invalid values in HTML attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5:

Any HTML5 validator (†) should be able to report this, because `styelsheet` is not a valid link type.

You may only use link types that are

- [defined in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#linkTypes), or
- [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#other-link-types) in the Microformats wiki [existing-rel-values](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) page.

† There are various validators available for Firefox, and I can’t recommend one (and it would be off-topic here anyway), but our sister site [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might help.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing prevents you from *extending* the `link` element with your own custom `rel` attribute. Due to this, the browser probably chooses to remain silent, assuming you know what you're doing :)

I would encourage you to get an editor that helps here, and leverage the auto-complete/suggestion features of said editor. For example, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (and other editors) will tab-complete the entire element for you: see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find misspellings within `link`s specifically, this will catch most:

```
var links= document.querySelectorAll('link');

for(var i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++) {
  if(!links[i].rel || links[i].rel !== 'stylesheet' || !links[i].href) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+links[i].outerHTML);
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffzucL63/)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox web developer tools will show that your stylesheet was not loaded, sometimes as an error if it can detect that. Right click on your page and select "Inspect Element" or ctrl-Shift-Q. You can look in the network panel to see what was downloaded. Perhaps other areas there will also highlight your link as a problem.

So, yes, Firefox, and other browsers, will flag that line as a problem in some way.